# Can I embed an A-Frame scene into Squarespace?

Tags: embed, aframe, squarespace

I want to embed this [a-frame project](https://detang2.github.io/sustainability/) to my portfolio on Squarespace (most basic plan) like what a-frame shows in their [embedded page](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/embedded.html) but I'm not even sure if it's possible? I'm also super new to coding so let me know if I should provide more info. If people can also explain things in baby language that would be awesome thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### embedding remote a-scene?

if you want to link your existing project to a different page then... I don't think it's possible. Look:

[image]

the documentation page uses a real a-scene there, with a-boxes and stuff.

It may be possible via iframes but I don't know if it works. There is something like this in the documentation:

> For now, if the I-Frame is not on the same origin as the page, the WebVR polyfill for mobile won’t work and there won’t be any tracked rotation of the device. - [source](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/embedded.html#using-i-frames)

#### embedded

`embedded` is used to create a smaller window of a-scene inside a standard HTML page. As far as I know, it just sets or changes some CSS values. Unfortunately, there is nothing like a magical `src` attribute that would allow you to fetch a different scene from another page

If you can upload a static HTML file onto Squarespace then by all means you can embed it there. But remember that

> Only one *<*a-scene*>* can exist on a page - same source

You would need to copy your entire project a-scene and paste it into your Squarespace page. Add A-Frame script in header or link a js file and all standard stuff.

#### link

this may not be what you are looking for but you could potentially create an embeded a-frame scene that would have a link inisde that would "teleport" you (change location) to your project. [link - A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/link.html)

Comment: wow this is super helpful! you've given me enough information for me to know that it's not possible to do what I'm thinking about. I'll need to be able to code into the current Squarespace HTML and I don't think the plan I have allows that. but it's okay. still thank you so much! the link is also very helpful! i didn't know that was a thing

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and am in a similar understanding of html.

This worked for me putting a 360 image in to squarespace. I'm not confident it is lovely code, i've probably got much of it wrong. But it worked for what I wanted. Hope it helps someone.

//

```
    <!--call the class in JS-->

<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<!--embedding window-->
    <a-scene embedded class="tester">

<!--make it visable in the preview-->
    
<div id="div1" style="height: 180px; width=270px">

</div>
 
<!--the image-->

<a-sky src="YOUR 360 IMAGE URL HERE" data-pin-no-hover="true" class="css-1ozkk90">
 
</a-sky>
        
<!--correct aspect ratio--> 
            vr-mode-ui='enabled: false' embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280;   sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280;  displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

<!--aframe camera-->
<a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader>

</a-camera>

</a-scene>
<p align="center">This is an example of a 360 space
</p>
```

//